# What OpenGL state needs to be reset upon a new shared context?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3, glfw

I have the following class to represent a Mesh;

```
OpenGLMesh::OpenGLMesh(const std::vector<float>& vertexData, const std::vector<float>& normalData, const std::vector<float>& texCoords, const std::vector<uint32_t>& indexData) : mIndices(indexData.size())
     {
        glGenBuffers(1, &mVBO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &mIndexBuffer);
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &mVAO);

        // buffer vertex, normals and index data
        size_t vertexDataSize   = vertexData.size() * sizeof(float);
        size_t normalDataSize   = normalData.size() * sizeof(float);
        size_t texCoordDataSize = texCoords.size() * sizeof(float);
        size_t indexDataSize    = indexData.size() * sizeof(uint32_t);

        glBindVertexArray(mVAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexDataSize + normalDataSize + texCoordDataSize, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL, vertexDataSize, &vertexData[0]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexDataSize, normalDataSize, &normalData[0]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexDataSize + normalDataSize, texCoordDataSize, &texCoords[0]);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndexBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexDataSize, &indexData[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)(vertexDataSize));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)(vertexDataSize + normalDataSize));

       // unbind array buffer and VAO
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
     }
```

And then a method to draw the mesh;

```
void OpenGLMesh::Render()
{
    glBindVertexArray(mVAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

I am using GLFW3 where you can create a new window and use the same context as the previous window ([link](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__window.html#ga5c336fddf2cbb5b92f65f10fb6043344)), however as I understand it you still need to reset the OpenGL states even though the buffer objects and their contents are still saved - correct?

I tried reading on the manual but I cannot find out what parts of the code I posted is treated as part of OpenGL state and needs to be reset?

Comment: Please do not use "NULL" when you mean 0. Like here: `glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL, vertexDataSize, &vertexData[0]);`

Comment: Because it's confusing. `NULL` is generally assumed to be a pointer, so people will have to figure out why you're passing a pointer as an integer. Whereas if you had just used an actual *integer*, they would understand what it's doing immediately. Indeed, some compilers will define `NULL` as `(void*)0`, which is a perfectly legitimate null pointer constant as far as the C++ standard is concerned. And that definition will stop your code from compiling altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> create a new window and use the *same context*

Not quite. GLFW will create a new context that [shares some of the other contexts' objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Object_Sharing). Namely ever object that holds some data (textures, buffer objects, shaders and programs, etc) will be shared, i.e. accessible from both contexts. Container objects, which reference other objects, are not shared (framebuffer objects, vertex array objects).

> however as I understand it you still need to reset the OpenGL states

Technically the newly created contexts start in a reset default state, with some objects already preallocated and initialized.

However like any state machine you should never assume OpenGL to be in a certain state when you're about to use it. Always make sure you set all the required state right before you need it *when* you need it. Which boils down, that you should set each and every state you require at the beginning of your drawing code.